# What are these commands: <!--#if FIREFOX, <!--#include

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

In a JS-Project I work with (pdf.js) I find commands like this in a HTML-File:

```
<!--#if FIREFOX || MOZCENTRAL-->
    <!--#include viewer-snippet-firefox-extension.html-->
<!--#endif-->
```

What they should do is quite obvious, but what are they? At first I thought it might be SSI, but the Syntax is a little bit different. Also it's apparently impossible to google the Syntax properly, so I ask you the probably dumb question what it is!

Comment: It looks alot like conditional comments targetted at firefox, but since firefox doesn't have conditional comments, it might be part of some templating language.

Comment: Add quotes around the code when googling, that gave me this answer:  https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7192
So its part of pdf.js' preprocessing

Comment: It's the pdf.js's preprocessor. If you run the code without compiling/processing, the browser will ignore commented code, when processed -- the commented code will be removed or uncommented (for #else case).

Comment: Yeah but what *is* this preprocessor? Something developed only for pdf.js? And if that, how can i run it?

Comment: See source code for it at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/external/builder/builder.js

Comment: Thank you, I didn't found that don't know why. If you want to write it as an answer I can approve the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the PDF.js's own preprocessor. If you run the code without compiling/processing, the browser will ignore the commented code, and when processed -- the commented code will be removed or uncommented (for #else case).

See source code for it at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/external/builder/builder.js